# How to host a Jupyter Notebook to allow user inputs for file paths but no code edits

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, web-hosting, jupyter-lab

I wrote a program to zip files for my work to use on a jupyter notebook. I want to make sure that the code cannot be accidentally be changed or messed with due to the users not having the knowledge to fix. But I want them to be able to run the code and utilize the input functions for inserting file pathways.

I've done research and cannot find a free host that would allow me to lock the code for no editing and not just post the frozen notebook not allowing the user to insert their inputs.

Much is appreciated

Comment: Having it have access to your user's local pathways makes it a hard fit for a lot of current things. I think [nteract](https://nteract.io/) might fit but I'm not sure how it does with access to local files. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49345672/8508004) for some other ideas. Voici is Voila built into JupyterLite but it wouldn't have access to local file paths. And you title needs to be more particular. There's a million ways to **host a Jupyter Notebook, but most of them aren't what you want.** Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Wayne Thank you for the comment and the suggestion. Ill fix that